# c++ for range loop quicker than decrementing loop

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, for-loop

#### We often loop over arrays starting with the last elment in this way:

```
static const char* pszStrings[] = { ... }
for (size_t i = _countof(pszStrings); i--;)
    use(pszStrings[i]);
```

#### My question is, if the new range based for loop is as efficient and so to be used:

```
static const char* pszStrings[] = { ... }
for (auto string : pszStrings)
    use(string);
```

#### Additionally …

Since I'm not able to take a look at the generated code, and even if, I don't know, if I'd be able to make the right conclusions, I'll be glad for not too scientific answers!

Comment: The range-based loop will iterate in the other direction, so you're comparing two loops which do different things.

Comment: `We often loop over arrays starting with the last elment in this way`, i find this sad, do you actually really need the micro optimisation this might brings you more than writing understandable code ?

Comment: Yes @interjay, I compare two different loops.

We use the "backward" loop with an empty iterator block, if the direction is not important.

Comment: Yes @Drax, we need in our system a micro optimization.

Just because the production simulation system may be used for very huge scenarious, where every ensured memory aligment, prevented memory fragmentation, every saved CPU cycle could affect the simulation speed and runtime positively!

Answer (score 5):

The compiler can make a lot of assumption about the iterated collection in the new `range for-loop`, that in the previously written for-loop. Example:

In C++98 days normally one write:

```
for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = v.begin(), it_end = v.end(); 
     it != it_end; ++it) {
    // code ..
}
```

The `it_end` was used because in a lot of case the compiler could not be sure that the collection would not change size inside the for-loop (and `.end()` could change). If you write:

```
for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
    // code ..
}
```

The compiler can generate a call to the `.end()` function for every execution of the loop.

The `range for-loop` is as efficient (some times more efficient) that the old for-loop.

Some examples:

If you have a loop iterating a `std::vector` by index: `for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)` this loop would need to index the vector to use the element (`v[i]`) most sure not a noticeable wait, but when vector are really big, in a tight loop could be notice.

This kind of loop would improve when updated to `range for-loop`.

The first loop in the answer most probably would not improve in performance, but would in clarity, the reader of the code would know that the code is meant to iterate **all the collection** and not skip some elements (in the old way, you could recognize the `for-each pattern` in the for-loop, but it's tedious and could lead to erroneous conclusions (probably in the body are modifying the index or the iterator) about the code if not careful.

Comment: Our backward for loop has an empty last section, so during runtime there is nothing to do at the loop end.
This could save some ticks.

The range-based-for is hopefully enough optimized to prevent unnecessary calls to methods, like `end()`.

I would prefer the range-based-for loop just because of its readability, and the ease in writing the the body of the loop.